# PM2 fails to start NodeJS Express Webapps, no errors though

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have a web app written in NodeJS/Express that runs fine when I run it from the command line. I am trying to get it to run under pm2 so that it runs continuously, restarting when necessary.

It worked fine for a while, but then stopped working for some reason. Now, when I try to restart it in pm2, it seems to start fine (it gets to the "online" state), but then errors out (changing to the "errored" state). But there are no errors in any of the log files.

I've added a function to the Express app that should log any error stack traces (app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { console.error(err.stack)... ), but that doesn't even show up in the pm2 log files.

I've tried reinstalling pm2, deleting various things in the .pm2 directory, and a few other things, but nothing seems to work at all.

pm2 version 2.1.5

Comment: You might have an easier time getting help if you actually post the information folks need to help you, e.g. what commands you're running, what your pm2 config file(s) look like, what OS you're on, etc.

Comment: hello Edward, please pos an issue there: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues so we can help you inspect this issue

Comment: OS= GNU/Linux. I've added the web apps to PM2 by simply running `pm2 start app.js`. I'm not using any specific pm2 config files, so the module_conf.json in the .pm2 directory is just {}.